# Why does canPreviewItem on QLPreviewController fail for supported file formats (like PDF) on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, ios12, quicklook

Checking `[QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:item]` for supported items, e.g. PDF files, returns `false` on iOS 13 but not on iOS 12. If you ignore this check and still attempt to display the item using `QLPreviewController`, you just get a screen displaying the file name (on iOS 12 the contents are displayed).

According to [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller?language=objc), `QLPreviewController` still supports showing PDF files, so does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. I made a quick app that previews a PDF, and `QLPreviewController.canPreviewItem(_:)` returns `true` for the PDF's file URL on iOS 13.

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution for this, iOS 13 will check if file exist or not in local path, while iOS 12 not, that's why they returned different.

Comment: Do not ask questions in the Answer field.